# Query method in codeigniter 4 does not work

Tags: php, postgresql, codeigniter, codeigniter-4

I tried for a long time to create a query for postgresql, I set the Database.php file in the framework, but I don't know what happened what the query does not work.

> Database.php

```
public $default = [
    'DSN'      => '',
    'hostname' => 'localhost',
    'username' => 'postgres',
    'password' => 'admin',
    'database' => 'mascotas',
    'DBDriver' => 'postgre',
    'DBPrefix' => '',
    'pConnect' => false,
    'DBDebug'  => (ENVIRONMENT !== 'production'),
    'cacheOn'  => false,
    'cacheDir' => '',
    'charset'  => 'utf8',
    'DBCollat' => 'utf8_general_ci',
    'swapPre'  => '',
    'encrypt'  => false,
    'compress' => false,
    'strictOn' => false,
    'failover' => [],
    'port'     => 5432,
];
```

This is my Database.php file in Codeigniter 4 Config

> Registro.php controller

```
public function formulario_registro()
{
    $db = \Config\Database::connect(); 
    $query = $db->query('SELECT VERSION()'); // Problems with this Query method
}
```

In the browser

[image]

My browser, when I call the `$query = $db->query('SELECT VERSION()');` method; I'm getting that Whoops error, I don't know what I'm doing wrong, I've already set the Database.php file and I'm following the official documentation

I really know what is wrong in my code, what I need or what happened

I need to be able to do any kind of query in the postgresql database, I have tried to connect using the official codeigniter 4 documentation, however I get that error in the browser when I call that method `$query = $db->query('SELECT VERSION()');`

I don't know why I get that, and I can't succeed in postgresql query

Basically I need to be able to query postgresql and I get this error

I have changed to development codeigniter 4 and I get this error

> Unable to connect to the database
>
> SYSTEMPATH\Database\BaseConnection.php at line 425

```
throw new DatabaseException('Unable to connect to the database.');
```

Comment: First thing first you should turn your environment to dev mode by editing .env file and setting `CI_ENVIRONMENT = development`. It will allow you to see actual errors instead of the "Whoops" page which is for production usage. Also be careful with the DBDriver parameter in your Database config since it's case sensitive. Try replacing `'DBDriver' => 'postgre'` with `'DBDriver' => 'Postegre'`. I have never used Postregre so I don't know the driver name but remember that the case must match it.

Comment: I changed the enviroment to development. The database mascotas already exists on my server pg

Comment: Regarding your error check out your username and db password and be sure to have your postregre server up and running. Also have in mind that there's 2 ways to setting db configs in CI4 : either Database.php (the file in your answer) or the .env file. The .env file overwrites Database.php so make sure you don't have an other db config in this file.